# "System.Data.DataRowView" in form load using combobox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Every time my forms loads/open it will prompt "System.Data.DataRowView", How can I possibly remove this?

Here is my code:

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetProcessorCardTypes();
    }

    private void GetProcessorCardTypes()
    {
        cn.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("call GetProcessorMethod(1)", cn);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        cmbProcessorMethods.DataSource = dt;
        cmbProcessorMethods.ValueMember = "method_id";
        cmbProcessorMethods.DisplayMember = "method_name";
    }

    private void cmbProcessorMethods_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(cmbProcessorMethods.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely remove message box, then remove `cmbProcessorMethods_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. Or you can change it to display `method_name` of selected row:

```
private void cmbProcessorMethods_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataRowView row = (DataRowView)cmbProcessorMethods.SelectedItem;
     MessageBox.Show(row["method_name"].ToString());
}
```

---

As Derek pointed, just set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties before assigning data source and your original code will work:

```
cmbProcessorMethods.ValueMember = "method_id";
cmbProcessorMethods.DisplayMember = "method_name";
cmbProcessorMethods.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: But I want the display the valuemember in messagebox everytime I change the index of the combobox

Comment: This will sound daft, but add your datasource last, after you have set the Valuemember & Displaymember. I think ive had this happen before. You also need to close your connection too.

Comment: @GrayFullBuster then use `row["method_id"].ToString()`

Comment: @Derek I think you should post your comment as an answer